# pandas dot product only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe that is called `xTest` and this vector x
both of type `numpy.ndarray`
x length is 197
`xtest`'s shape is (25000, 197).
I am trying of generate a new column for `xTest` called prediction by getting the dot product of `xTest` and `x`.

I tried:

```
xTest["pred"] = np.dot(xTest,x)
```

and

```
xTest["pred"] = xTest.dot(x)
```

I keep getting this error:
`IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`.

`xTest` is already one hot encoded.

UPDATE :
Thanks to the great person who pointed it out below
I was able to solve it like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["pred"] = np.dot(xTest,x)
```

Comment: What is the result of `print(type(xTest))`?

Comment: @user17242583 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: @user17242583 both has the same type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beacuse `xTest` is a numpy array and not a `dataframe`, you cannot use strings to index it. You're trying to access `pred` on `xTest` assuming `xTest` is a dataframe, but it's only a single column from a dataframe.